# Downloading backup TGZ from adminhtml fails

Tags: magento2, backup, download

After I make a backup from adminhtml, it shows up in the list and it shows up in the backend too. I have an option to download the backup TGZ file, as shown here:

[image]

When I click it though, the download fails. Chrome says "Failed - Network error":
[image]

**This happened after I accidentally deleted the entire `var/` folder under my Magento root directory.**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a var/ folder and give it 777 permission. Use below Command:

```
magento_root>  chmod 777 -R var/
```

After that check .htaccess in var/ folder and replace its content with :

```
#Order deny,allow 
#Deny from all
```

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: Are the hashes necessary in the .htaccess file?

Comment: No it's not. This file restrict the download from var/ folder. May be now you are able to download the backup tz file.

Comment: Did not work. All tgz files are chmoded to 777 but same error occurs. Do i need to reflush cache or something?